# GitHub fails to determine the repository language

Tags: qt, github, github-linguist

I use GitHub for a C++ / Qt project. GitHub automatically determines the languages of the project from the file extentions. Problem: Qt has a file name ProjectName.pro, which is interpreted to be Prolog by GitHub.

How can I indicate it is NOT Prolog, but C++ ?

Comment: What is the content of this file? GitHub has a tendancy of misjudgning file type, especially small files.

Comment: The .pro file of a Qt project only contains the included library and the name of the source and headers files. It's very small, only 11 lines.

Comment: Is the entire repo considered Prolog?

Comment: Heh, now I know why Github thinks I have prolog experience.

Comment: @larsmans No, but 3% of it is. And on my profile it's written I code with C++ and Prolog, which is wrong, I only code in C++, not in Prolog at all.

Answer (score 2):

It is actually a known issue: https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/394

It's been submitted 6 month ago but GitHub still doesn't bother fixing it... Do you think of any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

As said in the original issue (https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/394):

> Linguist now supports custom overrides for language definitions and
>   custom vendor paths

So in order to finally have Qt project files properly recognized as C++ in language statistics, you can add this line in your .gitattributes file.

```
*.pro linguist-language=C++
```

See https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides for more details.